# Catch and handle clicks on outbound links in vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm building a small webapp that gets data from a CMS. I'm using the Vue-Router in `history` mode. The content I'm fetching from the API can contain links, and I want to handle links that match certain criteria via the router, but anything I can't match should just be handled normally.

Is anything like this even possible? I've tried replacing the `<a>` tags inside the content with router-links, but that doesn't work, since I'm displaying the content with `v-html`. In jQuery I would've listened to events on all `<a>` elements and checked the links there, but I'm not sure how I can handle this in Vue (in an elegant way).

Comment: please share what you has tried so far

Comment: You probably want to parse the HTML and create objects in an array from those links that shall be handled by vue. Then you create vue router links from that array. However, for more specific advice a more specific example of what HTML you get and what HTML you want to create would be necessary.

Comment: I've replaced all occurences of links with router-links inside my api route and I've added a global click eventhandler inside my root app component. This actually works but I'm hoping there is a way I can maybe configure the router without me having to handle each and every generated click event. I don't like that I have to check parents of clicked elements to find out if a link was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your need correctly, you want to compile  components from dynamic content you are binding? I've had a very similar problem and came across this thread in the vue forum where a solution was proposed: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamically-compile-router-link/7410/3

LinusBorg sugggests using a dynamic computed component like this, with a transformer method that would parse links and turns them into router links:

```js
computed: {
  transformed() {
    return {
      template: transformer(...),
      props: this.$options.props
    }
  }
}
```

and then dynamically binding it in the template

```html
<component v-bind:is="transformed" v-bind="$props"/>
```

After playing around with this for a while, it did exactly what i wanted it to do, i had a transformer method that would replace  tags with router links and returned the string as new template to the transformed "component"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want! I'm going to give this a shot.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Made a single file component out of the codepen linked in that forum thread and it works like a charm.